# What is Polkadot?

Tags: polkadot

I am new to blockchain and I would like to understand what Polkadot is.

Are there any resources that can be helpful for me to learn?

Thank you

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ60bTU1bPg&t=9s) video on the Polkadot ecosystem which is explained in simple terms.

Comment: See also: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7/whats-the-difference-between-substrate-and-polkadot/

Answer (score 1):

You can start here:

- https://polkadot.network

Then delve into the Polkadot concepts:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/getting-started

Polkadot uses Substrate so it is good that you have a solid understanding of it.

Familiarize yourself with all the Substrate documentation:

- https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals

More beginner friendly resources can be found here:

- [How do I become a Substrate Developer?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/how-do-i-become-a-substrate-developer/1082#1082)

Futhermore, the [Web3 Foundation has launched educational courses with EdX](https://medium.com/web3foundation/polkadot-web3-educational-courses-launching-on-edx-9a67f4f6f731) (the same platform used by MIT, Harvard, Berkley University of California, Boston University).

The courses will start on Oct 27 2022, and will be archived for your benefit:

- [Introduction to Polkadot](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-polkadot)
- [Introduction to Blockchain and Web3](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-blockchain-and-web3)