# the difference between polkadot validators and substrate validators: are they the same?

Tags: validator

I use substrate in order to develop polkadot and I need depth information about substrate validators. There are a lot of data about polkadot validators but i haven't seen usefull data about substrate validators. Are they the same? If no, please help me get the information I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validators in Polkadot:

In Polkadot, validators refer to the entities that participate in the consensus algorithm called GRANDPA (GHOST-based Recursive Ancestor Deriving Prefix Agreement). These validators are responsible for producing and finalizing blocks in the Polkadot network.
Validators in Polkadot are selected based on their stake in the network's native token, DOT. The more DOT tokens a validator holds, the higher their chances of being selected to participate in block production and consensus.
Validators in Polkadot play a crucial role in maintaining the security and integrity of the network.
Validators in Substrate:

In Substrate, validators have a broader meaning and can refer to entities that perform various tasks within a Substrate-based blockchain. The term "validator" can encompass multiple roles, including block production, consensus, transaction validation, and more.
Substrate allows for flexible customization of blockchain functionality, and the specific responsibilities and roles of validators can be defined by the design and implementation of the Substrate-based blockchain itself.
Validators in Substrate can be involved in block production, transaction validation, executing runtime logic, executing smart contracts, and other tasks necessary for the operation of the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Substrate is a `Software Development Kit (SDK)` that allows you to build application-specific blockchains that can run as standalone services or in parallel with other chains with the shared security provided by the `Polkadot ecosystem.`

[Validators](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-validator) are participants in a `blockchain network` who play a crucial role in achieving consensus and securing the network. They validate and verify transactions, propose new blocks, and participate in the consensus mechanism to maintain the integrity and security of the blockchain.

you can also check [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7/whats-the-difference-between-substrate-and-polkadot)